# Netscaler - commit configuration changes to GIT

Tags: netscaler, cisco-nso

Our team frequently makes configuration changes to our Netscalers using the Netscaler Web UI, we'd like for each change to be committed to a GIT repo so we can track the changes over time.

Is there any feature in Netscaler which allows us to do this easily?

Answer (score 0):

There are tools like HPNA, Cisco NSO which can be configured to take running config backup on change and then you can commit to git.

Answer (score 0):

not exactly what you are looking for but the last 5 saved configs are located in /nsconfig/ns.conf*